# servletcontextlistener is not invoking

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, servlet-listeners

why follow contextlistener is not invoking on  first request  or server startup.

```
package com.kk.HTTP.listener;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;;

public class WebApplicationListener  implements ServletContextListener{

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Destroyed");
}

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("init");
}

}
```

in web.xml

```
<web-app>

<listener>
<listener-class>com.kk.HTTP.listener.WebApplicationListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

am i missing something. please answer.

Comment: What do your startup logs show? Post them.

Comment: Where are looking for the SOP's output? Are you running it from an IDE such as Eclipse?